# How to use the timeMin parameter while still fetching recurring events that have a start date less than timeMin but still recur?

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using the Google Calendar API, and I want to set timeMin to the current date so that I don't just fetch everything in the past, yet I also want to receive, in the response, all the recurring events that have a start date less than the current date but that still recur into the future.

Answer (score 0):

Well and that is precisely what the calendar API does when you specify timeMin parameter. It will still give you all the recurring events that have in instance in the specified time-range even if they started long time ago ;)

Comment: The API does not seem to return recurring events that have an originalStartTime that's less than the timeMin I specify. I know it might be the expected behavior, but is there a way to get these events without leaving out the timeMin parameter?

Comment: Could you paste the request you are sending? The originalStartTime is a property of instances of recurring events, not the recurring events themselves. If you want the full expansion of a recurring event I propose you use the instances() service call.

Comment: The request I'm sending is simply timeMin set to the current date. Everything else is just default. I want the recurring rule - I do not want the rule to be expanded into separate single instances.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on in your case. Would you give me an example of a recurring event and timeMin where the event ends up not retrieved? I have just checked a daily recurring event starting last week, set up the timeMin to today and got the recurring event back.